# Append-Only Comment is incorrectly duplicated when using "Check In file" action in Flow/Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I am using an Append Only Comment field in my SharePoint list, which I am updating via a Microsoft Automate workflow.  I do this several times in a single Flow, and it works great at the start of the Flow.

The problem I have is: when I finally use a "Check In file" action at the end of my flow, the last comment is duplicated.  Is there a way I can avoid this duplication?

Much appreciated.

Comment: how did you design your flow? To understand this issue better, please provide some screenshots about your flow actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using an Update Item action that simply sets the Append-Only Comment field to null.